# elastic collision of balls

Tags: java

i am having a bug which i can't figure out.I tried many times,the collision detection and calculating new velocities seems fine ,but some balls seem to stuck with each other i don't why.Can you please help me out.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ElasticCollision extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final int WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
    private static final int SCALE = 3;

    private static final String TITLE = "Elastic collision";

    private boolean running = false;

    private JFrame frame;
    private Thread thread;

    private Random random = new Random();
    private Color color;
    private int a, b, c;

    private Ball[] ball;
    private int x = 0, y = 0;
    private int radius = 0;
    private int speedX = 0, speedY = 0;

    private int noOfBalls = 25;

    private double newVelX1 = 0, newVelY1 = 0;
    private double newVelX2 = 0, newVelY2 = 0;

    private double angle1 = 0, angle2 = 0, angle3 = 0;
    private int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0;

    public ElasticCollision() {

        Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
        setPreferredSize(size);
        frame = new JFrame();
        ball = new Ball[noOfBalls];
    }

    public void start() {
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfBalls; i++) {
            x = random.nextInt(getWidth());
            y = random.nextInt(getHeight());
            radius = 25 + random.nextInt(25);
            speedX = 1 + random.nextInt(2);
            speedY = 1 + random.nextInt(2);
            ball[i] = new Ball(x, y, radius, speedX, speedY);
        }
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double unprocessed = 0;
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000.0 / 60;
        int frames = 0;
        int ticks = 0;
        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            unprocessed += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            while (unprocessed >= 1) {
                ticks++;
                update();

                unprocessed -= 1;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfBalls; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < noOfBalls; j++) {
                    if (ball[i].inCollision != true
                            || ball[j].inCollision != true)
                        checkCollision(ball[i], ball[j]);
                }
            }
            frames++;
            render();
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer > 1000) {
                lastTimer += 1000;
                frame.setTitle(TITLE + " | " + ticks + " ticks, " + frames
                        + " fps");
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }

        }
        stop();
    }

    public void update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfBalls; i++) {
            ball[i].x += ball[i].speedX;
            ball[i].y += ball[i].speedY;

            if (ball[i].x >= getWidth() - ball[i].radius && ball[i].speedX > 0)
                ball[i].speedX = -ball[i].speedX;
            if (ball[i].x <= ball[i].radius && ball[i].speedX < 0)
                ball[i].speedX = -ball[i].speedX;
            if (ball[i].y >= getHeight() - ball[i].radius && ball[i].speedY > 0)
                ball[i].speedY = -ball[i].speedY;
            if (ball[i].y <= ball[i].radius && ball[i].speedY < 0)
                ball[i].speedY = -ball[i].speedY;
        }
    }

    public void render() {

        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfBalls; i++)
            ball[i].paint(g);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void checkCollision(Ball ball1, Ball ball2) {
        double distance;

        if (ball1.x + ball1.radius + ball2.radius > ball2.x
                && ball1.x < ball1.x + ball1.radius + ball2.radius
                && ball1.y + ball1.radius + ball2.radius > ball2.y
                && ball1.y < ball2.y + ball1.radius + ball2.radius) {

            distance = Math.sqrt(((ball1.x - ball2.x) * (ball1.x - ball2.x))
                    + ((ball1.y - ball2.y) * (ball1.y - ball2.y)));
            if ((int) distance < ball1.radius + ball2.radius) {
                ball1.collision = true;
                ball2.collision = true;
                ball1.inCollision = true;
                ball2.inCollision = true;

                ball1.collisionX = ((ball1.x * ball2.radius) + (ball2.x * ball1.radius))
                        / (ball1.radius + ball2.radius) + ball1.radius;
                ball1.collisionY = ((ball1.y * ball2.radius) + (ball2.y * ball1.radius))
                        / (ball1.radius + ball2.radius) + ball1.radius;

                ball2.collisionX = ((ball1.x * ball2.radius) + (ball2.x * ball1.radius))
                        / (ball1.radius + ball2.radius) + ball2.radius;
                ball2.collisionY =

                ((ball1.y * ball2.radius) + (ball2.y * ball1.radius))
                        / (ball1.radius + ball2.radius) + ball2.radius;


                /*
                 * x1 = (ball1.x - getWidth()) / 2; y1 = (ball2.y - getHeight())
                 * / 2; angle1 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y1, x1));
                 * 
                 * x2 = (ball1.x - getWidth()) / 2; y2 = (ball2.y - getHeight())
                 * / 2; angle2 = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y2, x2));
                 */
                double colision_angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(
                        (ball2.y - ball1.y), (ball2.x - ball1.x)));

                double speed1 = Math.sqrt(ball1.speedX * ball1.speedX
                        + ball1.speedY * ball1.speedY);
                double speed2 = Math.sqrt(ball2.speedX * ball2.speedX
                        + ball2.speedY * ball2.speedY);

                double direction1 = Math.atan2(ball1.speedY, ball1.speedX);
                double direction2 = Math.atan2(ball2.speedY, ball2.speedX);

                double vx_1 = speed1 * Math.cos(direction1 - colision_angle);
                double vy_1 = speed1 * Math.sin(direction1 - colision_angle);
                double vx_2 = speed2 * Math.cos(direction2 - colision_angle);
                double vy_2 = speed2 * Math.sin(direction2 - colision_angle);

                double final_vx_1 = ((ball1.radius - ball2.radius) * vx_1 + (ball2.radius + ball2.radius)
                        * vx_2)
                        / (ball1.radius + ball2.radius);
                double final_vx_2 = ((ball1.radius + ball1.radius) * vx_1 + (ball2.radius - ball1.radius)
                        * vx_2)
                        / (ball1.radius + ball2.radius);

                double final_vy_1 = vy_1;
                double final_vy_2 = vy_2;

                newVelX1 = (int) (Math.cos(colision_angle) * final_vx_1 + Math
                        .cos(colision_angle + Math.PI / 2) * final_vy_1);
                newVelY1 = (int) (Math.sin(colision_angle) * final_vx_1 + Math
                        .sin(colision_angle + Math.PI / 2) * final_vy_1);
                newVelX2 = (int) (Math.cos(colision_angle) * final_vx_2 + Math
                        .cos(colision_angle + Math.PI / 2) * final_vy_2);
                newVelY2 = (int) (Math.sin(colision_angle) * final_vx_2 + Math
                        .sin(colision_angle + Math.PI / 2) * final_vy_2);

                ball1.speedX = (int) newVelX1;
                ball1.speedY = (int) newVelY1;

                ball2.speedX = (int) newVelX2;
                ball2.speedY = (int) newVelY2;

                ball1.x = ball1.x + (int) newVelX1;
                ball1.y = ball1.y + (int) newVelY1;
                ball2.x = ball2.x + (int) newVelX2;
                ball2.y = ball2.y + (int) newVelY2;




            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ElasticCollision balls = new ElasticCollision();
        balls.frame.setResizable(false);
        balls.frame.add(balls);
        balls.frame.pack();
        balls.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        balls.frame.setVisible(true);

        balls.start();
    }

}

class Ball {

    protected int x = 0, y = 0;
    protected int radius;
    protected int speedX = 0, speedY = 0;
    protected boolean collision = false;

    protected int collisionX = 0, collisionY = 0;
    protected boolean inCollision = false;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int radius, int speedX, int speedY) {
        this.x = x + radius;
        this.y = y + radius;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (!collision) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(collisionX - radius, collisionY - radius, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(collisionX - radius, collisionY - radius, 20, 20);
            collision = false;
            inCollision = false;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your logic doesn't let the balls move apart once the collision is detected. Only change the direction of movement once and not every instant the balls are close to one another.

Comment: My code woks perfectly until this one                                                             ball1.speedX = (int) newVelX1;
ball1.speedY = (int) newVelY1;

                ball2.speedX = (int) newVelX2;
                ball2.speedY = (int) newVelY2;

                ball1.x = ball1.x + (int) newVelX1;
                ball1.y = ball1.y + (int) newVelY1;
                ball2.x = ball2.x + (int) newVelX2;
                ball2.y = ball2.y + (int) newVelY2;